# Function calling in openerp reports

Tags: python, report, reportlab, odoo

How is this `sum_taxes` method getting its `lot` parameter set? This is a code sample from the auction addon in openerp.

```
    import pooler
    import time
    from report import report_sxw
    from osv import osv

    class seller_form_report(report_sxw.rml_parse):
        def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):
            super(seller_form_report, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
            lot=self.pool.get('auction.lots').browse(cr,uid,uid)
            #address=lot.bord_vnd_id.address_get(self.cr,self.uid,[partner.id])
        #   partner=lot.bord_vnd_id.partner_id
        #   address=partner.address and partner.address[0] or ""
        #   street = address and address.street or ""



            self.localcontext.update({
                'time': time,
                'sum_taxes': self.sum_taxes,
                'sellerinfo' : self.seller_info,
                'grand_total' : self.grand_seller_total,
        #       'street':street,
        #       'address':address,
    })


    def sum_taxes(self, lot):
        taxes=[]
        amount=0.0
        if lot.bord_vnd_id.tax_id:
            taxes.append(lot.bord_vnd_id.tax_id)
        elif lot.auction_id and lot.auction_id.seller_costs:
            taxes += lot.auction_id.seller_costs
        tax=self.pool.get('account.tax').compute(self.cr,self.uid,taxes,lot.obj_price,1)
        for t in tax:
            amount+=t['amount']
        return amount
    def seller_info(self):
        objects = [object for object in self.localcontext.get('objects')]
        ret_dict = {}
        ret_list = []
        for object in objects:

            partner = ret_dict.get(object.bord_vnd_id.partner_id.id,False)
            if not partner:
                ret_dict[object.bord_vnd_id.partner_id.id] = {'partner' : object.bord_vnd_id.partner_id or False,'lots':[object]}
            else:
                lots = partner.get('lots')
                lots.append(object)
#       buyer_ids=self.pool.get(auction.lots).read(cr,uid,lot)
        return ret_dict.values()
    def grand_seller_total(self,o):
        grand_total = 0
        for oo in o:
            grand_total =grand_total + oo['obj_price']+ self.sum_taxes(oo)
        return grand_total


report_sxw.report_sxw('report.seller_form_report', 'auction.lots', 'addons/auction/report/seller_form_report.rml', parser=seller_form_report)
# vim:expandtab:smartindent:tabstop=4:softtabstop=4:shiftwidth=4:
```

Answer (score 1):

check following file auction/report/buyer_form_report.sxw
`[[ repeatIn(o['lots'],'oo') ]] [[ oo.obj_num ]]` Here 'oo' is defined and its called like `[[ oo.obj_price  + sum_taxes(oo) ]]`

and as this report is registered for the model: `auction.lots` it will return the `BrowseRecord` for the `active_id` when user clicks on report !!!

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually calling the function in that code, the function probably gets called from within the report and passes the lot parameter there. In the code example you posted, it's just putting a function pointer into the context.

For more info on OpenERP reports, check out the [reports section](http://doc.openerp.com/developer/3_11_reports/index.html) of the developer book. I also find it really helpful to run the OpenERP server in Eclipse and step through the code in debug mode. Then you can see where the `sum_taxes()` method is being called from.